# How to sent a variable content to other page?

Tags: php, html

I got a form that define the content of a variable.

The variable is $option and the content depends of the option selected in the form:

```
<form action="result.php" method="post">
<br>
<table>
<tr><td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="Button1" value="1" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="Button2" value="2" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="Button3" value="3" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="Button4" value="4" /></td></tr>
</table>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Show result"><br><br>
</div>
</form>
```

Then result.php file set the correspond variable content correctly:

```
<?php error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
if ($_POST['Button1'] == '1') {
    $option = First;
}
if ($_POST['Button2'] == '2') {
    $option = Second;
}
if ($_POST['Button3'] == '3') {
    $option = Third;
}
if ($_POST['Button4'] == '4') {
    $option = Four;
}
?>

<html>
The option choosen is <?php echo $option;?>
</html>
```

But now I need go to result2.php from result.php file and get the same variable content.

I have tried doing this in result2.php:

```
<?php 
if (['$option'] == '1') {
    $option = First;
}
if (['$option'] == '2') {
    $option = Second;
}
if (['$option'] == '3') {
    $option = Third;
}
if (['$option'] == '4') {
    $option = Four;
}
?>
```

But the $option variable dont get the value stored from result.php because the result2.php don't get the information.

So how I can sent the variable content from result.php set from index.html to result2.php?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello and thanks for reply. I don't know if I've explained myself well. My form is working good. The result.php file get the value selected and save the information in the variable $option. The problem is that from result.php I have another form with action=result2.php and I want sent the information of my variable ($option) to result2.php file.

Comment: Just echo an input with the variable and set it to display none if you don't want the user to see it or send the variable via url and use GET...you can also set the variable as a session cookie